# What is keeping my PC from sleeping?

Tags: windows, power-management, acpi

How can I find out why my laptop or desktop won't automatically go to sleep

Comment: Have you spilled coffee on it recently?  OK OK that's lame...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that Windows 7 is the only version of Windows which can tell you what devices are preventing the machine from sleeping. Windows 7 and Vista can tell you what devices are armed to wake the device from sleep.

There is a tool called [powercfg](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940.aspx) which can do this. New to Windows 7 is the ability to see what is armed.

**Windows 7**

1. Open an elevated command prompt
2. Type **powercfg /requests**

You will see a list of items preventing the machine from entering sleep.

Comment: Those commands should be used in conjunction with Kevin's answer to get a comprehensive list

Comment: This works for Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 14):

Vista also has powercfg.exe, which can tell you which devices are armed to wake the system from sleep:

powercfg -devicequery wake_armed

as well as which device last woke the machine from sleep:

powercfg -lastwake

Sounds like Windows 7 got some new features though.

Comment: Those commands should be used in conjunction with Omar's answer to get a comprehensive list

Answer (score 1):

you can also run `powercfg -energy` from an elevated cmd. this will monitor your PC for 60secs during which you should continue using it normally.

A report is generated at the end. Looking at Errors in this report should give you a clue as to what is preventing your PC from going to sleep.

one of the most common issues is Media sharing. This shows up as `\Filesystem\srvnet` in the report. You will need to turn off media sharing to get rid of this issue.

If its something different, do post any questions you have. thanks

Comment: The fact that `\Filesystem\srvnet` often prevents the system going stanby is correct. But setting `Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service` to disabled in the services MMC doesn't get rid of `srvnet` blocking standby. So I am a bit confused...

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while but this solved it for me. Create a batch file with the following content:

```
powercfg -requestsoverride PROCESS chrome.exe awaymode display system
net stop "Windows Update" & net start "Windows Update"
```

(the second part of the net command is not mandatory because the service restarts anyway)

... then create a Windows task to execute the batch file every 30 minutes (don't forget to add execute in privileged mode.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, here is what it was in my case.

My computer was reporting (via [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15846912/1073106)) that user inputs were received more than once a second, all the time.

After disabling both the keyboard and the mouse with no change, I removed all usb devices and connected them one by one while checking for idle.

The culprit turned out to be a WingMan joystick, that was powered off but still connected to the usb port. As soon as I disconnected it the computer was idling properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a `Power-Troubleshooter` source within Vista's Event Viewer in the Application event log with related information such as Wake Source.